# Align single and double-line containers

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-float

I have a header row where some of the header names are too long to fit on one line and have to be split. The headers are fixed height, sufficient for two lines. The text should be vertically centered.

Something like:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
.pill {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="pill">
    Header One
  </div>
  <div class="pill split">
    Header
    <br/>Two
  </div>
  <div class="pill">
    Header Three
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't figure out how to align all those headers correctly. Setting `line-height` to 40px makes the second header double-height; setting height to 40px throws them out of alignment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what I changed in your code:

1. Add `vertical-align: middle` to align the `pill`s
2. Give `line-height` same as height for the `pill`s other than `split` using the `not` selector:

   ```
   .pill:not(.split) {
     line-height: 40px;
   }
   ```
3. In smaller displays the menu will wrap - so use `float` and `clear` them too.

Let me know your thoughts on this, thanks!

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
.pill {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
}
.pill:not(.split) {
  line-height: 40px;
}
.pill:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="pill">
    Header One
  </div>
  <div class="pill split">
    Header
    <br/>Two
  </div>
  <div class="pill">
    Header Three
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
}
.pill {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  margin: 0 1%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="pill">
    Header One
  </div>
  <div class="pill split">
    LONG HEADER TEXT GOES HERE
  </div>
  <div class="pill">
    Header Three
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is change the way you are setting the elements side by side, so instead of `inline-block`:

## Table-cell

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
.pill {
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid white;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33%;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="pill">
    Header One
  </div>
  <div class="pill">
    Header
    <br/>Two
  </div>
  <div class="pill">
    Header Three
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `.pill` css:

```
vertical-align:middle;
```

[Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/r8hksLjh/2/)